# CMake knows std 20, but g++9 doesn't

Tags: cmake, g++, std

I have a project, which cannot be compiled by a fellow, due to an unknown call to a method from the std library.
I suspect that it's due to the fellow's g++ version (9.4.2) because the function was added in the std 20 standard. To test if that is the case I installed g++-9 (Version 9.5.0) and pointed the `/usr/bin/g++` symbolic link to g++-9 and stumbled upon another issue (**the question**).

When I run

```
$ g++-9 -std=c++20
g++-9: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=20’; did you mean ‘-std=c2x’?
g++-9: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I get an error stating, that the std standard version 20 is unknown.
But when I try to generate the build files for an cmake project with the following line in the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        cxx_std_20
)
```

I get no error. But when replacing the 20 with a 23:

```
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        cxx_std_23
)
```

I get the error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:74 (target_compile_features):
  target_compile_features The compiler feature "cxx_std_23" is not known to
  CXX compiler

  "GNU"

  version 9.5.0.
```

Why is the C++20 standard unknown to g++, but known, when generating build files with cmake?

---

This is some sort of follow up Question:

When I try to compile my project I get the error:

```
error: ‘std::stringstream’ {aka ‘class std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>’} has no member named ‘view’
```

and [view was added in c++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/view). Can it be, that view was jet not added in c++2a?

Comment: I purposely created a symlink from `g++ -> g++-9`, to  be sure cmake used g++-9, therefore the output is the same (I also checked it).

Comment: Oh, my bad. I missed that. Sorry for that mistake. But I typed c++20 in my terminal, just the question was wrong. Therefore the output didn't change. Let me quickly edit my question.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++2a` works, but cmake still thinks that c++20 is okay (which g++ tells me otherwise)

Comment: It's the same. GCC has always provided aliases for the not-yet-released standard versions. See `man gcc`, it's the same. It's also what CMake uses under the hood.

Comment: This is some sort of follow up question then:  
when I try to compile my project I get the error: `error: ‘std::stringstream’ {aka ‘class std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>’} has no member named ‘view’`, which [was added in c++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/view). Can it be, that view was jet not added in c++2a?

Comment: Thanks for your quick and helpful reply. Can you add your the last comment to your answer? Then I will accept your answer with pleasure.

Comment: Please move your follow-up question to its own question post- **checking first** that that question has not already been asked. As a general rule, you should only ask one question per question post.

Comment: Note: you don't actually need to modify the file system to get cmake to use a specific compiler; simply setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` to the absolute paths to the `g++`/`gcc` programs you want cmake to use in a cmake script file and passing this file during the initial cmake configuration via `--toolchain` option is sufficient, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html . Alternatively simply make sure that set the [`CXX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXX.html) and `CC` environment variables are set to the compiler paths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the option for standard C++20 up to GCC 9 is `-std=c++2a`. According to `man gcc`:

> c++2a
>
> The next revision of the ISO C++ standard, planned for 2020. Support is highly experimental, and will almost certainly change in incompatible ways in future releases.

So not all features can be expected to be in there.

GCC has a tradition of providing aliases for the not yet released standards or those with incomplete support. GCC 9 only knows `c++2a` and that became an alias for `c++20` with GCC 10.

CMake can handle this. When in doubt what CMake uses as standard (or any other option), take a look in the build directory in `flags.make` or `build.ninja` (depending on which generator you're using).

Comment: Even with `g++-9 -std=c++20` the output is the same: `g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++20’; did you mean ‘-std=c++2a’?`

Answer (score 2):

Well... if your compiler is GCC 9.5.0, the reason why CMake says your compiler doesn't know about C++23 is because... it doesn't?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

The only thing that cppreference.com's compiler support table says that GCC v9 "knows" about C++23 is "*Narrowing contextual conversions in `static_assert` and `constexpr if`*"

And the reason why you get "*g++-9: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=20’; did you mean ‘-std=c2x’?*" for GCC 9.5.0 is probably just because C++20 support wasn't fully implemented yet. Again, look at the compiler support table in cppreference.com. There are lots of core language features and library features for C++20 that GCC didn't implement until version 10 (some even in version 9-13 Ex. "*Atomic Compare-And-Exchange with padding bits*")

So just do what it told you to do and take what you get, accepting that not all of the C++20 features will be available in GCC 9.5.0.

Or upgrade you compiler :P

The reason why it works with CMake's `target_compile_features(... cxx_std_20)` is because... CMake handles it.

See [Modules/Compiler/GNU-C.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/GNU-C.cmake):

> ```
> if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 9.1)
>   set(CMAKE_C23_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION "-std=c2x")
>   set(CMAKE_C23_EXTENSION_COMPILE_OPTION "-std=gnu2x")
> endif()
> ```

and [Modules/Compiler/GNU-CXX.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/GNU-CXX.cmake):

> ```
> elseif(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 8.0)
>   set(CMAKE_CXX20_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION "-std=c++2a")
>   set(CMAKE_CXX20_EXTENSION_COMPILE_OPTION "-std=gnu++2a")
> endif()
> ```

Comment: Link to the compiler support table is helpful and missing from my answer. +1